# Process within a Timer

Tags: c#, windows, process, timer

My program uses this method to invoke a new process:

```
public List<string> NewChangesets(string location)
        {
             var changeInfoProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    WorkingDirectory = location,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    FileName = "hg",
                    Arguments = "incoming",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                }
            };

            changeInfoProcess.Start();
```

It works fine when it is called normally, but when it is invoked from a timer it will sit on the `.Start()` method and not advance any further. I have tried setting the priority of the current thread to the highest, but no luck.

This is how I set up my timer:

System.Threading.Timer is the timer I am using

```
TimerCallback partTimerDelegate = new TimerCallback(Build);

Timer partTimerItem = new Timer(partTimerDelegate, (object)false, 0, (int)new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Any reason why this doesn't work in a Timer callback?

Comment: What do you mean by "not advanced any further?" are you running the program in debug mode?

Comment: Yes when I pause the program in debug mode it is stopped at that line.  I have given it a about 20 minutes to see if it will advance any further but it will not.